# Text below image in grid made with divs

Tags: html, css

I made a grid with divs and there are images on it. Now i want to get the text directly below image somehow. I don't know how to do it. This is my code:

```
<div id="grid">
     <div id="gridtop1">
     <img src="img/img.jpeg" />
     <p>Text here</p>
     </div>
     <div id="gridtop2">
     <img src="img/img.jpeg" />
     <p>Text here</p>
     </div>
     <div id="gridtop3">
     <img src="img/img.jpeg" />
     <p>Text here</p>
     </div>
     <div id="gridbottom1">
     <img src="img/img.jpeg" />
     <p>Text here</p>
     </div>
     <div id="gridbottom2">
     <img src="img/img.jpeg" />
     <p>Text here</p>
     </div>
     <div id="gridbottom3">
     <img src="img/img.jpeg" />
     <p>Text here</p>
     </div>   
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#grid   {
        position: relative;
        left: 10%;
        width: 80%;
        height: 600;
        background-color: yellow;
}
#gridtop1 {
          position: absolute;
          left: 10%;
          top: 5%;
}
#gridtop2 {
          position: absolute;
          left: 40%;
          top: 5%;
}
#gridtop3 {
          position: absolute;
          right: 10%;
          top: 5%;
}
#gridbottom1 {
             position: absolute;
             top: 55%;
             left: 10%;
}
#gridbottom2 {
             position: absolute;
             top: 55%;
             left: 40%;
}
#gridbottom3 {
             position: absolute;
             top: 55%;
             right: 10%;
}
```

Now i tried this:

```
#grid p {
    text-align: justify;
    width: [width of img];
}
```

But it didn't help.
I don't want to make different id for all the p tags. I'm pretty close to giving up and using tables for this. But would be nice to get this to work. The text is below the image but it starts in the middle and goes all the way to the next image. Please someone help i spent like 3 hours trying to solve it.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle? it can be very useful to test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont think you have to sweat so much on the CSS.

Please check this fiddle out and let me know if that solves your problem -

You can implement it by simple CSS (using `float` and `position`)

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ankitjc/b4gdz/)

Comment: Well i already tried with float. Now i tried again and same thing. It works without text but when i add text it pushes the next image and they all get messed up. It's funny thet it works on that fiddle thing but doesen't when i try to edit my page

Comment: So u need to decide on few things before implementing this- To start with 1) how many images you need to have in one row. 2) Position of the images and text. 

Are you going to have 4 images or 6 images in one row?

Comment: Do "display:block" on the paragraph tags, that way they will automatically take up an entire line of their own instead of pushing all the content over.

Comment: Dont worry, Everyday's a learning. Glad you were able get it done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 tags as `<figure>` and `<figcaption>` (instead of div & p )and display `<figure>` as inline-boxes.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpqEx)** *(see image caption set below or hover at bottom of image)*

```
  <figure>
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x150&text=img-2" />
    <figcaption>
      <p>Caption image</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
```

Basic CSS :

```
figure {
  margin:2px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

to center them, use `text-align:center` on `figure` parent container. to have them on the right or left, use `text-align:right`or`left;`.

text in `figcaption` , will use `width` of image as reference given for the width of `figure`.

if you set figcaption in absolute position, you do not have to mind their width.

Comment: Thanks m8. That solved it. Got the images and texts aligned perfectly.

Comment: @Pau-Lee ?? you accepted the other answer , was this comment meant for another answer ?

Comment: This works also but figcaption is not very well supported but both answers were good